# Retain rows in a multidimensional array if the subarray has at least one value in a qualifying numeric range

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, range, filtering

I have a multidimensional array. I want to get array element which value is greater than 2 and less than 17. My Array is given below:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 12
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

I want output like below:

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 15
            [2] => 12
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )
)
```

Please help me how can I do it easy & fast method.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested array filter.

```
$result = array_filter($outer_array, function($inner_array) {
    return array_filter($inner_array, function($number) {
        return $number > 2 && $number < 17;
    });
});
```

Then inner array filter will result in an empty array being passed to the outer array filter if no values are found in the specified range. The empty array will evaluate to false in the outer filter callback, eliminating that array from the result.

[Demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/mrJfv).

Answer (score 1):

Generally, we want you to show what you have tried before we'll write code for you, but this one's on the house. For future reference, include some code snippets along with your question to avoid getting downvoted.

```
$output = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    $use = false;
    for($j = 0; $j < count($arr[$i]); $j++)
    {
        if($arr[$i][$j] > 2 and $arr[$i][$j] < 17)
        {
            $use = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($use)
        $output[] = $arr[$i];
}

return $output;
```

Comment: Hi David, Please read my question and check which output I want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a classic/breakable loop inside of `array_filter()` for best efficiency inside of a functional style script.

Nesting `array_filter()` inside of `array_filter()` will not permit an "early return" and therefore will cost unnecessary cycles after a subset's data has already been deemed satisfactory.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JI7uh))

```
var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function($set) {
            foreach ($set as $v) {
                if ($v > 2 && $v < 17) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    )
);
```